# pandas filter by quantiles results in an empty set

Tags: python, pandas, filter

How can a `pandas.Series` cut into quantiles be filtered by quantile bins? My three different approaches here either fail outright or result in an empty set.

The desired solution would use `df.query()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_series':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
df['quantile'] = pd.qcut(df.my_series, [0,0.5,0.6,1])
print(df)
#df[df.quantile == '(4.6, 7.0]'] # fails with key error :false

df['string_quantiles'] = df['quantile'].astype(object)
print(df)
display(df[df['string_quantiles'] == '(4.6, 7.0]']) # no failure, but empty set

df.query("my_series == '(0.999, 4.0]'") # empty set
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `astype` convert it

```
yourdf=df[df['string_quantiles'].astype(str)=='(4.6, 7.0]'].copy()
Out[60]: 
   my_series    quantile string_quantiles
4          5  (4.6, 7.0]       (4.6, 7.0]
5          6  (4.6, 7.0]       (4.6, 7.0]
6          7  (4.6, 7.0]       (4.6, 7.0]
```

Or

```
df[df['quantile'].map(lambda x : x.left)==4.6].copy()
```

Comment: lol!  Then I was going to do this one and then... there you were (-:

Answer (score 4):

`pd.cut` returns `Interval` objects. So, just create one and compare:

```
df[df['quantile'] == pd.Interval(4.6, 7)]

   my_series    quantile
4          5  (4.6, 7.0]
5          6  (4.6, 7.0]
6          7  (4.6, 7.0]
```

Comment: my fgitw days are passed me (-:

Comment: @piRSquared I'll take that as a complement :P

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `codes` attribute of the `Categorical`

```
df[df['quantile'].cat.codes == 2]

   my_series    quantile
4          5  (4.6, 7.0]
5          6  (4.6, 7.0]
6          7  (4.6, 7.0]
```

Knowing that

```
df['quantile'].cat.categories[2]

Interval(4.6, 7.0, closed='right')
```